# How to bind a $scope variable to a normal variable in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS controller, I have a variable `$scope.name` which is assigned to an input's `ngModel`.

I wanted to save the value of `$scope.name` to a normal variable, so I could process it in my controller without changing the value of the input box.

So I did `var name = $scope.name`

The issue is, now the two seem to be linked... when I change the value of `name`, the value of `$scope.name` also changes, and that changes the value of the input box.

How can I stop this? How can I assign a `$scope` variable to normal variable, once, without any continued binding?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use angular.copy()

like:

```
var name;
$scope.name = 'name';

function copy(){
    name = angular.copy($scope.name);
}
```

[See more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Comment: Perfect, thank you - I'll Accept this as soon as the site lets me